# Should I use anchor tag with next/link in Next.js for SEO?

Tags: seo, links, button, next.js

Is there some SEO advantage to using an anchor tag inside next/link?

For example if I prefer to use a button like this

```
import Link from 'next/link'

<Link href='/somewhere' passHref>
  <MyButton>Go Somewhere</MyButton>
</Link>
```

Would that be worse for SEO than this?

```
import Link from 'next/link'

<Link href='/somewhere' passHref>
  <a>Go Somewhere</a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on what `MyButton` component actually renders. The second case is always correct, since it renders regular `a` tag (`a href="https://www.google.com">Go somewhere</a>`), and it will work without javascript enabled (good for SEO).